# How to permanently writing the com to a file

Tags: batch-file

I need to write all that com give me to a file. I'm trying with:

```
type com3 > result.txt
```

But only write the first line.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `copy com3 result.txt` work better?

Comment: The issue might be caused by how `type` handles the `com` device; can you exclude that the device receives an end-of-file marker (ASCII 0x1A)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting, while you should be appending:

```
type com3 >> result.txt
```

Comment: The `>` operator doesn't care about lines, it just redirects the whole (binary) input data to a file and overwrites an already existing one…